# How to avoid downtime when restarting ECS Fargate services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, aws-cdk

I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash    
myClusterId="myCluster"
for service in $(aws ecs list-services --cluster $myClusterId --query "serviceArns[*]" | jq -r 'to_entries[] | .value | sub(".*/";"")'); do
    for task in $( aws ecs list-tasks --cluster $myClusterId --service-name $service --desired-status 'RUNNING' --no-paginate --output text --query 'taskArns[*]' ) ; do 
        aws ecs stop-task --cluster $myClusterId --task $task --reason "Restarted using bash script" > /dev/null 2>&1
    done
done
```

In short, it will restart all my ECS Fargate tasks under *myCluster* (excluding scheduled tasks triggered by CloudWatch Rules). It's working fine so far.

All my services have [minHealthyPercent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ecs.FargateService.html#minhealthypercent) set to 100 and [maxHealthyPercent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ecs.FargateService.html#maxhealthypercent) set to 200. But, I noticed that it didn't keep any healthy tasks during the restart process. All tasks get killed immedietly and my load balancer throws *503 Service Temporarily Unavailable* error when new tasks are in pending/provisioning state.

[image]

Am I missing something in my script? How do I correctly perform no-downtime services restart process using AWS CLI?

Answer (score 2):

The parameters [maximumPercent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-service-deploymentconfiguration.html#cfn-ecs-service-deploymentconfiguration-maximumpercent) and [minimumHealthyPercent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-service-deploymentconfiguration.html#cfn-ecs-service-deploymentconfiguration-minimumhealthypercent) are only used during [rolling updates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/deployment-type-ecs.html) of your ECS service:

> The number of tasks that Amazon ECS adds or removes from the service during a rolling update is controlled by the deployment configuration. A deployment configuration consists of the **minimum and maximum number of tasks** allowed during a service deployment.

Restarting a task is **not considered** as a new deployment.

To rectify the issue, there are few choices:

- include a `sleep` in your for loop. Its the **crudest** way, but fastest to implement for testing.
- use [describe-tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-tasks.html) in the for loop to **pull the state of the task** just terminated. Proceed with restarting next task only when the state of the most recently restarted one will be `RUNNING`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option would be to do a blue/green deployment through CodeDeploy, assuming you use an Elastic Load Balancer. The blue/green deployment will automatically detect any error and stop the deployment if required.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/use-aws-codedeploy-to-implement-blue-green-deployments-for-aws-fargate-and-amazon-ecs/